# How to add custom syntax highlighting in ipython for Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

For our in-house programming language I would like to offer syntax highlighting in Jupyter Lab. I couldn't find a resource how to do this. Is this something I need to announce to ipython?